# Reimplementing function using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, windows, algorithm

The purpose of `version_from_path(path)` is to return the version number of a Python installation, given the absolute path to the default named and targeted root directory of that installation on a Windows system (e.g `'C:\PythonXX'`).

```
def version_from_path(path):
    return "%s.%s" % (path[-2:-1], path[-1:])
```

As an example...

```
print(version_from_path('C:\Python27'))
print(version_from_path('C:\Python32'))
print(version_from_path('C:\Python33'))
```

...produces...

```
2.7
3.2
3.3
```

I'm currently using slice notation and a formatting operation to achieve the required results, however I would be interested to see how the same functionality is achieved using a regular expression.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you want to handle three-digit version numbers (e.g., `C:\Python101` or `C:\Python314`)? Or do you not care what happens in those cases?

Comment: @Ted Hopp I had only considered two-digit version numbers. Being able to handle three-digit version numbers would be a bonus.

Comment: A bonus, yeah, but how? In the first case, is it 1.01 or 10.1? In the second is it 3.14 or 31.4?

Comment: @Ted Hopp In your example, wouldn't the three digits be representative of a `major.minor.revision` version numbering scheme? So for instance 101 and 314 would be 1.0.1 and 3.1.4 respectively. In any case I'd be interested to see how that is formatted.

Comment: @richardlambert Are you aware that the version numbers are available in [`sys.version_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.version_info)?

Comment: @RolandSmith: I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @Roland Smith No I wasn't aware so thank you for pointing that out, however in the grand scheme of things my path strings are acquired through user input in this case.

Comment: @richardlambert As a design consideration I don't think you should bother the user about something that can be extracted from the system. For one thing it prevents errors. In this case, while most people will let the Windows installer use the default location, you _can_ choose a different one. In which case your code will almost certainly fail in some cases whatever you do. E.g. what about an installation path that doesn't even contain numbers or one that doesn't have them at the end. Like `C:\Python` or `C:\Python33-64bit`?

Comment: @RolandSmith Thank you. You make a good point which warrants further exploration on my part. I do however state that this function depends on the Python installation being made with a default named and targeted root directory and that I was querying the use of a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
return re.sub(r".*?(\d)(\d)", r"\1.\2", path)
```

If you want to capture all trailing digits and put the dot just before the last one:

```
return re.sub(r".*?(\d*?)(\d)$", r"\1.\2", path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = re.compile( r"C:\\Python(\d)(\d)" )

def version_from_path_re(path):
  m = regex.match( path )
  if m:
    return ".".join( map( str, m.groups() ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The version numbers are easily and in detail available in [sys.version_info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.version_info).

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: The question and comments imply to me that the Python installation at `path` is not necessarily the one that is running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the folder name itself, you could search in the file `include/patchlevel.h`:

```
def version_from_path(path):
    with open(path + '/include/patchlevel.h') as f:
        m = re.search(r'#define\s+PY_VERSION\s+"(\d+\.\d+)', f.read())
        if m:
            return m.group(1)
```